# Download not going to configured folder in Cypress test

Tags: cypress

I'm testing file download in multiple browsers. In Chrome it downloads as expected, but in Firefox the folder used is not the default `cypress/downloads` folder.

**DOM**

```html
<a data-cy="download-png" href="logo.png" download>logo.png</a>
```

**Test**

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="download-png"]').click()
```

Chrome:

> (download)  C:\ ... \cypress\downloads\logo.png

Firefox:

> (download)  C:\downloads\logo.png

Do I need special configuration or plugin for Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue, see [Cypress is not downloading files in the cypress/downloads folder on Firefox](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/17896).

If you upgrade to [Cypress v10.6.0](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/v10.6.0), it should be resolved.